# iOS "Control may reach end of non-void function"

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Any idea why I am getting 2 errors of the below code of "Control may reach end of non-void function"? I had it working in a separate app but for some reason coming up with this error now.

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [categoryTypes count];;
            break;
        case kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [locationTypes count];
            break;
        case kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [originatorTypes count];
            break;
        case kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [destinationTypes count];
            break;
        case kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [statusTypes count];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}



- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [locationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [statusTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Many Thanks

**UPDATE**

Full code:

```
@synthesize nameTextField, emailTextField, dateTextField, timeTextField, blankTextField, blankbTextField, mlabelcategory, messageTextView;
@synthesize name, emailaddress, date, time, blank, blankb, category, message;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        categoryTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Appetizers",@"Breakfast",@"Dessert",@"Drinks",
                         @"Main Dish/Entree", @"Salad", @"Side Dish", @"Soup", @"Snack",
                         @"Baby Food", @"Pet Food",nil];

        locationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                         @"Brazilian", @"British", @"Cajun", @"Central American", @"Chicken",
                         @"Chinese", @"Cuban",
                         @"Ethiopian", @"French", @"Greek", @"German", @"Hamburgers",
                         @"Homestyle Cooking", @"Indian", @"Irish", @"Italian", @"Jamaican",
                         @"Japanese", @"Korean", @"Mexican", @"Middle Eastern", @"Pakistani",
                         @"Pancakes /Waffles", @"Persian", @"Pizza", @"Polynesian", @"Russian",
                         @"Sandwiches", @"Seafood", @"Scandinavian", @"Spanish", @"Soul Food",
                         @"South American", @"Steak", @"Vegetarian", @"Tex-Mex", @"Thai",
                         @"Vietnamese",@"Wild Game",nil];

        originatorTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                           @"Brazilian", @"British", @"Cajun", @"Central American", @"Chicken",
                           @"Chinese", @"Cuban",
                           @"Ethiopian", @"French", @"Greek", @"German", @"Hamburgers",
                           @"Homestyle Cooking", @"Indian", @"Irish", @"Italian", @"Jamaican",
                           @"Japanese", @"Korean", @"Mexican", @"Middle Eastern", @"Pakistani",
                           @"Pancakes /Waffles", @"Persian", @"Pizza", @"Polynesian", @"Russian",
                           @"Sandwiches", @"Seafood", @"Scandinavian", @"Spanish", @"Soul Food",
                           @"South American", @"Steak", @"Vegetarian", @"Tex-Mex", @"Thai",
                           @"Vietnamese",@"Wild Game",nil];


        destinationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                            @"Brazilian", @"British", @"Cajun", @"Central American", @"Chicken",
                            @"Chinese", @"Cuban",
                            @"Ethiopian", @"French", @"Greek", @"German", @"Hamburgers",
                            @"Homestyle Cooking", @"Indian", @"Irish", @"Italian", @"Jamaican",
                            @"Japanese", @"Korean", @"Mexican", @"Middle Eastern", @"Pakistani",
                            @"Pancakes /Waffles", @"Persian", @"Pizza", @"Polynesian", @"Russian",
                            @"Sandwiches", @"Seafood", @"Scandinavian", @"Spanish", @"Soul Food",
                            @"South American", @"Steak", @"Vegetarian", @"Tex-Mex", @"Thai",
                            @"Vietnamese",@"Wild Game",nil];


        statusTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                       @"Brazilian", @"British", @"Cajun", @"Central American", @"Chicken",
                       @"Chinese", @"Cuban",
                       @"Ethiopian", @"French", @"Greek", @"German", @"Hamburgers",
                       @"Homestyle Cooking", @"Indian", @"Irish", @"Italian", @"Jamaican",
                       @"Japanese", @"Korean", @"Mexican", @"Middle Eastern", @"Pakistani",
                       @"Pancakes /Waffles", @"Persian", @"Pizza", @"Polynesian", @"Russian",
                       @"Sandwiches", @"Seafood", @"Scandinavian", @"Spanish", @"Soul Food",
                       @"South American", @"Steak", @"Vegetarian", @"Tex-Mex", @"Thai",
                       @"Vietnamese",@"Wild Game",nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    nameTextField.text = nil;
    emailTextField.text = nil;
    dateTextField.text = nil;
    timeTextField.text = nil;
    blankTextField.text = nil;
    blankbTextField.text = nil;
    mlabelcategory.text = nil;
    messageTextView.text = nil;

    categoryTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,400,400,160)];
    categoryTypePicker.tag = kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG;
    categoryTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    categoryTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    categoryTypePicker.delegate = self;
    categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    locationTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    locationTypePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    locationTypePicker.tag = kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG;
    locationTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    locationTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    locationTypePicker.delegate = self;
    originatorTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    originatorTypePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    originatorTypePicker.tag = kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG;
    originatorTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    originatorTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    originatorTypePicker.delegate = self;
    destinationTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    destinationTypePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    destinationTypePicker.tag = kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG;
    destinationTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    destinationTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    destinationTypePicker.delegate = self;
    statusTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    statusTypePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    statusTypePicker.tag = kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG;
    statusTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    statusTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    statusTypePicker.delegate = self;
}


/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)eve
{

    if ( !locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ( !categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ( !originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ( !destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ( !statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark picker methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return kPICKERCOLUMN;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [categoryTypes count];;
            break;
        case kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [locationTypes count];
            break;
        case kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [originatorTypes count];
            break;
        case kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [destinationTypes count];
            break;
        case kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [statusTypes count];
            break;
        default: return nil; break;
    }

}



- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [locationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [statusTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        default: return nil; break;

    }
}




- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG) {
        NSString *categoryType  = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [categoryTypeBtn setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else if (pickerView.tag == kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG) {

        NSString *locationType  = [locationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [locationTypeBtn setTitle:locationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else if (pickerView.tag == kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG) {

        NSString *originatorType  = [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [originatorTypeBtn setTitle:originatorType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else if (pickerView.tag == kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG) {

        NSString *destinationType  = [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [destinationTypeBtn setTitle:destinationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else if (pickerView.tag == kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG) {

        NSString *statusType  = [statusTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [statusTypeBtn setTitle:statusType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
-(IBAction) showLocationTypePicker{
    if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }



}
-(IBAction) showCategoryTypePicker{
    if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

-(IBAction) showOriginatorTypePicker{
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

-(IBAction) showDestinationTypePicker{
    if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }

}

-(IBAction) showStatusTypePicker{
    if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
        [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma - getting info from the UI

//NSString *test = nil;


- (IBAction)checkData:(id)sender
{
    /*
     name = nameTextField.text;
     surname = surnameTextField.text;
     bornDate = bornDateTextField.text;
     address = addressTextField.text;
     zipCode = zipTextField.text;
     email = emailTextField.text;
     */

    //NSLog(@" Name: %@ \n Surname: %@ \n Date of Birth: %@ \n Address: %@ \n Post Code: %@ \n email: %@ \n", name, surname, bornDate, address, zipCode, email);

    unsigned int x,a = 0;
    NSMutableString *emailmessage; //stringa variabile
    emailmessage = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @""]; //le stringhe mutabili vanno inizializzate in questo modo!


    for (x=0; x<7; x++)
    {
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                if (nameTextField.text == nil) {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Name, "];
                    a=1;

                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if (emailTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email Address, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (dateTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Date of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                if (timeTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Time of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                if (blankTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Post Code, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                if (blankbTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 6:
                if (mlabelcategory.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Category, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (messageTextView.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Observation Description, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    NSLog (@"Email Message: %@", emailmessage);

    if (a == 1) {

        NSMutableString  *popupError;
        popupError = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"Per inviare compilare i seguenti campi:  "];

        [popupError appendString:emailmessage]; //aggiungo i miei errori
        [popupError appendString: @" grazie della comprensione."]; //

        NSLog(@"%@", popupError);

        UIAlertView *chiamataEffettuata = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"ATTENTION" //titolo del mio foglio
                                           message:popupError
                                           delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok, correggo" //bottone con cui si chiude il messaggio
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [chiamataEffettuata show]; //istanza per mostrare effettivamente il messaggio
    }

    else
    {
        name = nameTextField.text;
        emailaddress = emailTextField.text;
        date = dateTextField.text;
        time = timeTextField.text;
        blank = blankTextField.text;
        blankb = blankbTextField.text;
        category = mlabelcategory.text;
        message = messageTextView.text;

        NSMutableString *nearmissreport;
        nearmissreport = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<br><br> <b>Name:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br> <b>Date of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>Time of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>Post Code:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br> <b>Category:</b> %@ <br><b>Observation Description:</b> %@ <br>", name, emailaddress, date, time, blank, blankb, category, message];

        NSLog(@"Near Miss Report: %@", nearmissreport);

        NSMutableString *testoMail;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: nearmissreport];

        NSLog(@"%@", testoMail);


        //MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        MFMailComposeViewController  *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController  alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject: name];

        // Set up the recipients.
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"paul.haddell@bbmmjv.com",nil];

        //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
        //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
        //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

        // Attach an image to the email.
        //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano" ofType:@"png"];
        //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];

        // Fill out the email body text.
        //NSMutableString *emailBody;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", testoMail];

        [picker setMessageBody:testoMail isHTML:YES]; //HTML!!!!!!

        // Present the mail composition interface.
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}


// The mail compose view controller delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Mandare email
/*
 - (void)sendMail:(NSMutableString*)testoMail{

 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 [picker setSubject:@"Reclutamento pompieri"];

 // Set up the recipients.
 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"reda.bousbah@gmail.com",nil];
 //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
 //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

 [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
 //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
 //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

 // Attach an image to the email.
 //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano" ofType:@"png"];
 //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
 //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];

 // Fill out the email body text.
 NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
 [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

 // Present the mail composition interface.
 [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


 }
 */



#pragma mark - methods to control the keyboard

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender //method for resign the keyboard when the background is tapped
{
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [dateTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [timeTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [blankTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [blankbTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [mlabelcategory resignFirstResponder];
    [messageTextView resignFirstResponder];

}

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"done button pressed");
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: missing default returns..outside of switch

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, what and where would I put the default returns?

Comment: try ...         default: return 0;
            break;
    } ... or whatever default you need instead of 0

Comment: Add a return to the end of the method, even `return nil` will do.

Comment: @gro that fixed the problem. The problem i've got now is that none of the arrays are showing up in the pickerviews!

Comment: which would indicate that .tag property is not correct

Comment: Would it be ok if I put the full code up and you could have a look where i've gone wrong with it? Many Thanks

Comment: well, I suspect it worked before because you were setting the tag property correctly on the pickeView. since it isn't set properly now, the original error was being thrown, as it processed the default case in the switch statement...and had no return.

Comment: I've added the full code. Is there anyway I can get the pickerviews showing the arrays again?

Comment: @PaulH the question about your picker views not showing correctly is a new question. Please post it separately as a different question so this doesn't become an extended discussion in the comments.

Comment: Sorry I will post a new question.

Comment: Woah woah woah! You don't create 5 pickers if you want to display 5 different kind of information. You create one single picker and modify the data source methods accordingly. If you'd like to show a different kind of information, you call `reloadAllComponents`.

Comment: This is the only way that I could get it to work. I had it working as a separate app but then when added it to the app i need it for it came up with the original errors but now won't show any array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because in case you tag property doesn't fall into any of the cases, it goes to the `default` block which in turn won't return anything.

You need to return a default value (`nil`,`0`) in the default block:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;
    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG: {
            numberOfRows = [categoryTypes count];
            break;
        }
        case kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG: {
            numberOfRows = [locationTypes count];
            break;
        }
        case kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG: {
            numberOfRows = [originatorTypes count];
            break;
        }
        case kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG: {
            numberOfRows = [destinationTypes count];
            break;
        }
        case kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG: {
            numberOfRows = [statusTypes count];
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

You'll also have to do this in the `titleForRow` method.

Also:

- I prefer having minimal amount of `returns` and modifying a value
  instead which I will return at the end
- Enclosing cases in `{}`.